# Visual Studio 2012 - Required file "tracker.exe" is missing

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cryengine

I tried to compile the source code of [cryengine 3](http://www.crydev.net/) and I always get the following error message.

```
Error   1   error : Required file "tracker.exe" is missing. C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets  251 6   CryGame
```

For some reason I couldn't find any information on google.

Could it be possible that my Visual Studio installtion is somehow corrupt? I am still using the release candidate

Comment: could be because your VS studio is using the wrong tracker.exe, is your machine 32bit or 64 bit

Comment: how about your VS? is it installed under 32-bit or 64-bit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A quote from MS website about tracker.exe:

> Tracker.exe is required to correctly incrementally generate resources
>   in some circumstances, such as when building on a 64-bit OS using
>   32-bit MSBuild. This build requires Tracker.exe, but it could not be
>   found. The task is looking for Tracker.exe beneath the
>   InstallationFolder value of the registry key
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A.

Possible solutions:

- Install the Microsoft Windows SDK v7.0A or later.
- Manually set the above registry key to the correct location.
- You short-circuit that lookup instead by setting the
  ResGenTrackerSdkPath property to the 7.1 .NET 4.0 tools location. In
  the build definition, under "MSbuild Arguments", you can add the
  following:

*/p:ResGenTrackerSdkPath=":\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools*

EDIT: your path may differ a little, but this still shows the general path to add

Comment: What if I only have version 7.1 installed, not 7.0a?

Comment: I am. But - I did a 'Repair' from Control **Panel | Programs | MS VS 2012** and that worked.

Comment: I ran into the same problem after upgrading windows SDK from 7.0a to 7.1 which was installed to the C:\Program Files\ directory (may be 64bit version) and VS2012 couldn't find it in that location. Running the repair from the Windows Control Panel fixed the problem.

Comment: Link to the Windows SDK for the lazy http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the directory `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows"`.

Then, you search for the key "tracker.exe", if you can't find it, it might been deleted somehow.

The best way is:

Copy the folder `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools"`

To your PC at the same directory.
 If it didn't work, you can copy the folder into them[the following picture] every one.

picture:
[image: picture]