# Visual Studio Express 2012 tracker.exe is missing

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I downloaded and registered Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Express for Desktop, and wrote a very simple C++ HelloWorld style program to see if everything worked. Sure enough, I am getting errors:

`Error  1   error : Required file "tracker.exe" is missing. C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets  249 5   Test`

The code is literally just:

```
#include "stdafx.h"


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::cout<<"Hello";
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Googling didn't help much. The only thing I found was that it might be due to the "tracker" that VS is using is a 32-bit tracker, and not a 64-bit one. I have no idea what a tracker is, and I wasn't able to choose which system to download VS for. I am running it on a 64-bit version of Windows 8.
Thanks!

~Carpetfizz

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2012 - Required file "tracker.exe" is missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422178/visual-studio-2012-required-file-tracker-exe-is-missing)

Comment: None of those suggestions worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed the problem by selecting the "Change" option in Control Panel > Uninstall a Program. This brings up the VS12 menu, and you have to select "Repair." This will run a process that should fix the problem.